# MDM Vendor creation - Apple Enterprise

Tags: ios, certificate, enterprise, mdm

They seemed to have changed things in the new enterprise certificates portal. Can someone be so kind as to tell me how to create a MDM vendor certificate (not the customer APNS Certificate: https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/) . This used to be under the Other tab under certificates in the ios provisioning portal. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it moved [here](https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/) based on this [mail](http://lists.apple.com/archives/greatlakes/2012/May/msg00002.html):

> If you created your APNS MDM certificate in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program, please see the "Learn more about MDM push certificate migration" link on the Apple Push Certificates Portal

Comment: No, I mean the MDM Vendor certificate. We are MDM Vendors and we need to generate the certificate so that we can sign customer's CSRs.

Answer (score 7):

I just called Apple for help on this as I also have an Enterprise account and no longer see that option.  They actually had to manually enable my account as an MDM Vendor account.  Once they did that, I went in to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiiles --->  IOS Certificates and clicked the (+) plus sign to create a new certificate.  Now that they enabled "MDM vendorship" in my account there is a new radio button under "Production" called "MDM CSR" where I can generate a new MDM certificate.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Had the same issue. Contacted Apple to activate the option "MDM Vendorship" through their support page https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php. The option got activated within the hour.